# Java Locale to get Sinhala/Sri Lankan Translation

Tags: java, internationalization, locale

I have JSF UI application and I want to display translated country names.

I am getting country names with Java Locale. But unable to get my transalation requirement. With Java 1.6 Locale provided only 44 Unique countries.

```
Locale[] localeArray =  Locale.getAvailableLocales();
System.out.println("localeArray---->"+localeArray.length);  

for (Locale locale : localeArray) {     
    counter++;
    System.out.print("locale-->"+locale+"-------");
    System.out.print("locale getISO3Language-->"+locale.getISO3Language());
    System.out.println("-----locale.getDisplayCountry(locale)--->"+locale.getDisplayCountry(locale));
    System.out.println("-----locale.getDisplayCountry()--->"+locale.getDisplayCountry());
    System.out.println("-----locale.getCountry()--->"+locale.getCountry());

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------"+counter);
}
```

Please let us know how to perform my requirement ?

Oracle documentation provide [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html#jfc).

Is there any available Libraries other than Java to perform powerful locale specific requirement?

Comment: Take a look at [ICU](http://icu-project.org/), but I doubt you'll find much more. I am not sure if there is even the translation in [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), but it is worth to check. At least with CLDR you may be able to implement language switcher antipattern (that's what you're up to, aren't you?)

Comment: I checked it already. But do not have working solution or method or guidelines. Is there any Apache commons facility ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I already suggested in the comment, you should have tried ICU for the purpose of getting native names of Locales. The simplest possible usage example:

```
ULocale locale = ULocale.forLanguageTag("si-LK");
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayName(locale));
```

This prints:

> සිංහල (ශ්‍රී ලංකාව)

I assume that the answer is correct. To convert this into the form suitable for UIViewRoot, you only need to call `toLocale()` method:

```
Locale javaLocale = locale.toLocale();
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I checked it by using icu4j-3.6.1.jar, but do not have method forLanguageTag in ULocale class. Please let us know the steps, jars that u have used.

Comment: @Ruchira: The current version of ICU is 52.1, as listed on [downloads page](http://site.icu-project.org/download). Unlike with other project, I would strongly recommend using the [latest possible version of ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download/52#TOC-ICU4J-Download) as it contains latest version of Unicode as well as CLDR.

Comment: සිංහල (ශ්‍රී ලංකාව). I got the output.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Locale locale = new Locale("si", "LK")
```